Dockerized NGINX Configuration with ReactJS App and Spring Boot Application Running Single Web app On Azure (Container Registry)
type here
I have a fairly standard ReactJS frontend (using port 3000) app which is served by areact JS backend server (using port 8080). Both apps are Dockerized and I have configured NGINX in order to proxy requests from the frontend to and from the server.
Dockerfile For Front end
FROM node:latest as build
#Set the working derectory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
#Add the source code to app
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --force

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]

Dockerfile for server:
FROM eclipse-temurin:17.0.6_10-jdk
WORKDIR /app
COPY target/go-pro-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]

nginx.conf file (in go-pro-client root)
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://go-pro-client:3000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://go-pro-server:8080/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}

and heare is a docker-compose.yml file.
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: "nginx-proxy"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      -./go-pro-client/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - go-pro-client

  go-pro-server:
    image: crgoprob2b.azurecr.io/go-pro-server:latest
    container_name: "go-pro-server"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

  go-pro-client:
    image: crgoprob2b.azurecr.io/go-pro-client:latest
    container_name: "go-pro-client"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - go-pro-server

with this configuration I have a one problom.

By running docker-compose up locally using http:// localhost/ url it works properly.
But By deploying Azure Web App using container type (Docker-compose (preview), goes to Nginx Welcome page.
Please help me for that.

Thanks for your time.
I try to deploy a react js and spring boot application using one Web App service. and I expected clicked azure url go to the client page and contact wit backend responses.

if possible please share your repo.
